# Names for related pairs of angles

Tags: trigonometry, terminology

I seek the names (if they exist) of two relationships between angles.

Two angles are **complements** of each other if they add up to a quarter circle.  $\sin\alpha=\cos\beta$ and vice versa.

Two angles are **supplements** of each other if they add up to a half circle.  $\sin\alpha=\sin\beta$ and $\cos\alpha=-\cos\beta$.

Two angles are **coterminal** to each other if they differ by some number of whole circles.   All trigonometric values are identical for both.

Two angles are **???? #1** of each other if they differ by a half circle.  $\sin\alpha=-\sin\beta$ and $\cos\alpha=-\cos\beta$.

Two angles are **???? #2** of each other if they add up to a whole circle (or zero). $\sin\alpha=-\sin\beta$ and $\cos\alpha=\cos\beta$.

[image]

Comment: No known names besides complement and supplement.

Comment: Well if they add to a circle then they are negatives of each other.

Comment: For #1 - you may call it "negative of it's supplement" i suppose...and #2 as "negative of itself"....as the diagram suggests